# Array output repeating one more then it should

Tags: java, arrays, string

This code basically takes a string array goes through it one at a time and displays a tally of each elements occurrence.

problem is that element number 3 ("One") is repeated at the end and im not sure why, so the out put i would get is:

**Current Output:**

```
One 2
Two 1
Three 1
One 2
```

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String [] myStrings = {"One", "Two", "Three", "One"};        
    StringCount(myStrings);        
}

public static void StringCount(String [] Array)
{
    int size = Array.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int count = 0; 

        String element = Array[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (Array[j].equals(element)){
                count ++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Array[i] + " " + count);
    }
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
One 2
Two 1
Three 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Set` to avoid duplicates like below:

```
public static void StringCount(String [] Array)
{
    int size = Array.length;
    Set<String> existingElement = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        int count = 0;

        String element = Array[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (Array[j].equals(element)){
                count ++;
            }
        }
        // This will print the result if and only if the element has not
        // already been added into the Set
        if (existingElement.add(Array[i])) {
            System.out.println(Array[i] + " " + count);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
One 2
Two 1
Three 1
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you get four printed lines because you call the output method inside a loop that runs exactly four times:

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // size is 4
{
    ...
    System.out.println(Array[i] + " " + count);
}
```

As you want to count the occurrences of all distinct strings, you want to *map* those strings to their count. The problem is that you can't know the exact number of distinct strings beforehand. So you have to build up such a map and loop again over its elements (in a second step):

```
Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

/* setup map */
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String element = Array[i];
    /* special case for having an element the first time: */
    if (!counts.containsKey(element)) {
        counts.put(element, Integer.valueOf(0));
    }
    /* increase the count for the element and store it back in map */
    int oldCount = counts.get(element).intValue();
    counts.put(element, Integer.valueOf(oldCount+1));
}

/* print out values */
for(String element : counts.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(element + " " + counts.get(element));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you check every element and you have One two times, so it will be checked twice! you need to have a set of checked elements so when you check element you put it in set, and then before checking next element you check if it is in set, if it is, then skip it.